# Unable to fetchdata from commerce.js api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRlCn.png)

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total_items')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total_items')
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:50:20)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35235:22)
    at updateFunctionComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38117:24)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39829:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24827:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24871:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24928:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44802:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44049:16)
    at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43972:9)
```

**App.jsx:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { commerce } from './lib/commerce'
import{ Products, Navbar } from './components'

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [ cart, setCart ] = useState({});

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list();
    setProducts(data);
  }

  const fetchCart = async () => {
    setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve());
  };

  const handleAddToCart = async (productId, quantity) => {
    const item = await commerce.cart.add(productId, quantity);

    setCart(item.cart);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchProducts();
    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  console.log(cart.total_items)
  return (
    <div>
        <Navbar totalItems={cart.total_items} />
        <Products products={products} onAddToCart={handleAddToCart}  />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The product.jsx file is attached.

Products.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

import Product from './Product/Product';
import useStyles from './styles';


const Products = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
    <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
            {products.map((product)=>
               <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
                <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
               </Grid>
            )}
        </Grid>
    </main>

     )
}

export default Products;
```

Product.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card, CardMedia, CardContent, CardActions, Typography, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import { AddShoppingCart } from '@material-ui/icons'

import useStyles from './styles';

const Product = ({ product, onAddToCart }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    
  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
        <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image.url} title={product.name} />
        <CardContent>
            <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                <Typography variant='h6' gutterBottom>
                    {product.name}
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant='h5'>
                    {product.price.formatted_with_symbol}
                </Typography>
            </div>
            <Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: product.description}} varient='body2' color="textSecondary" />
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
            <IconButton arial-lable="Add to Cart" onClick={() => onAddToCart(product.id, 1)}>
                <AddShoppingCart />
            </IconButton>
        </CardActions>

    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product,
```

The following is the navbar componet

**Navbar.jsx**:

```
const Navbar = ({ totalItems }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
        <AppBar postion="fixed" className={classes.appBar} color='inherit'>
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography varient="h6" className={classes.appBar} color='inherit'>
                <img src={logo} alt="VITB Market Place" height="25px" className={classes.image} />
                </Typography>
                <div className={classes.grow} />
                <div className={classes.button}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Show cart items" color="inherit">
                        <Badge badgeContent={totalItems} color="secondary">
                            <ShoppingCart />
                        </Badge>
                    </IconButton>
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    </>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

the above-mentioned file are the two other files.

I am expecting that the cart number should increase in real time but it is not happening. Instead it throws an error and when i reload the page the number increases

Comment: `cart` is `undefined` so I guess that `item.cart` is `undefined`

Comment: TypeError is because of getting props from undefined object (cart.total_items). If it is possible I recommend you to use  cart?.total_items || defaultValue. The other way is to const [cart, setCart] = useState({total_items : []}) <-defaultValue

Comment: Also, useEffect runs after render. Once component which receive cart.total_items is rendered, then your fetchData function work to update state. It means your Navbar gets undefined props first

Comment: @Konrad cart is defined

Comment: @Kangseohyun Still the error is not resolved. you need any other file to review the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote at the comment. Seeing the React Lifecycle Docs, react lifecycle is like render > useEffect > render. It means there is no value at the first render. there is no cart.total_items, product.name, product.price ...etc.

first render (your initial state) :

```
cart = {}
product = []
```

In this state, you extract `cart.total_items` <- it is undefined

Also, Products component crashes too.

```
const Products = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
const classes = useStyles();

const noItems = products.length === 0;
return(
<main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
    <Grid container justify="center" spacing={4}>
        // if there is no products list, react doesn't render Product component.
        {!noItems && products.map((product)=>
           <Grid item key={product.id} xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
            <Product product={product} onAddToCart={onAddToCart} />
           </Grid>
        )}
    </Grid>
</main>

 )
```

Comment: the products are fetched from commerce.js api

Comment: But the render is faster than fetch

Comment: [image of website on loading](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Untitled.jpg)

Comment: Can you please edit that particular code to render i am unable to get it

Comment: @HarshShukla I think the products component is done. Would you please write the NavBar Component. I don't know NavBar uses what kind of keys in the cart props.

Comment: I have added the navbar also

Comment: @HarshShukla It is the props drills to Badge component. Would you please just tell me key in carts object.

Comment: [Link to the image](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Untitled_1.jpg) is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @HarshShukla Okey, const [ cart, setCart ] = useState({ total_items : 0});

Comment: It worked. But now i cant add items to my cart. like it is not displaying any number on the top

Comment: It is hard to fix because I don't know enough your code. How about <Navbar totalItems={cart?.total_items || 0} /> <- using optional chaining & const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(); <- remove {}